# How to read properties from config with the same name in sping boot app

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

i have an import config datamart.yaml.

```
spring:
  config:
    import: datamart.yaml
```

In datamart many properties with the same name, differ in first letter

```
datamarts:
  Test:
    streamname: test
    header: test
    priority: 1
    action: upload
  test:
    streamname: test.delete
    header: test
    priority: 111
    action: delete
```

The problem is that spring can't split the parameters and always use last `test`

```
@Data
@Component
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "datamarts", ignoreUnknownFields = false)
public class DatamartProperties {

    private DatamartType test = new DatamartType();

    @Data
    @AllArgsConstructor
    @NoArgsConstructor
    public static class DatamartType {

        private String streamname;
        private String header;
        private int priority;
        private String action;

    }
}
```

I try to set params from enviroment and its wokred. But Is there any easier way for set params using spring autoconfiguration

```
@Data
@Component
public class DatamartProperties {

    private final ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    private final DatamartType test;
    private final DatamartType testDelete;
    
    public DatamartProperties(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

        this.test = new DatamartType(
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.Test.streamname", String.class),
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.Test.header", String.class),
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.Test.priority", Integer.class),
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.Test.action", String.class)
        );

        this.testDelete = new DatamartType(
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.test.streamname", String.class),
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.test.header", String.class),
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.test.priority", Integer.class),
            applicationContext.getEnvironment().getProperty("datamarts.test.action", String.class)
        );
}
```

Comment: You have 2 different keys and only 1 field named "test" in configuration property class. You shoud use 2 fields , named "Test" and "test" , or Map<string,DatamartType> where keys will be "Test" and "test" in your case). Main problem in your example - you want to map 2 objects to 1 field. There is no field named "Test" thats why "always use the last test".

Comment: 1)Only 1 filed for exmaple. "Test" its wrong name, should be used camelCase. But even if such a name is used, there will be null.
2)In Map<String,DatamartType> parameters are not correct. Test.streamname = test.delete and test.streamname = test.delete

Comment: from https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/properties/source/ConfigurationPropertyName.html

"User created names may contain the characters "a-z" "0-9") and "-", they must be lower-case and must start with an alphanumeric character."

so you can use arrays and additional field to store key, for example